# fatal error while trying to send message using twilio

Tags: php, twilio

I got this fatal error while using twilio been working at it for 2 hours still cant figure it out

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\RestException' with message '[HTTP 400] Unable to create record' in /membri/deathcrow/server/sms/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Version.php:87 Stack trace: #0 /membri/deathcrow/server/sms/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Version.php(207): Twilio\Version->exception(Object(Twilio\Http\Response), 'Unable to creat...') #1 /membri/deathcrow/server/sms/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/MessageList.php(63): Twilio\Version->create('POST', '/Accounts/ACa81...', Array, Array) #2 /membri/deathcrow/server/sms/que.php(25): Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageList->create(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /membri/deathcrow/server/sms/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Version.php on line 87`

here is my full page coding I have hidden the sid,token, and numbers for security reasons

```php
<?
 require_once ("../connect.php");
 require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
 use Twilio\Rest\Client;
 ignore_user_abort (true);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM smsque ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";
 $query = mysql_query ($sql);
 $row = mysql_fetch_object ($query);

 $id = $row->id;
 $msg = $row->message;
 $amount = $row->amount;
 $reciever = $row->reciever;

 $headers = 'From: noReply@anon.com';

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = '******************';
$token = '*************';

$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$client->account->messages->create(array(
  "From" => "**********",
  "To" => "*******",
  "Body" => "Test!"));

    //mail ($to, '', $msg, $headers);

 $amount--;

 if ($amount >= 1){
  $sql2 = "UPDATE smsque SET amount='$amount' WHERE id='$id'";
  $query2 = mysql_query ($sql2);
 }else {
    $sql2 = "DELETE from smsque WHERE id='$id'";
     $query2 = mysql_query ($sql2);
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function call seems to be incorrect . To send an sms out "to" number is the first parameter in "create()" , see below  a generic call

```
$sms = $client->account->messages->create(

    // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
    $number,

    array(
        // Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number 
        // that you've purchased
        'from' => "+**********", 
        // the sms body
        'body' => "the sms body here "
    )
);
```

So your code should be actually like the one below

```
<?
 require_once ("../connect.php");
 require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
 use Twilio\Rest\Client;
 ignore_user_abort (true);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM smsque ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";
 $query = mysql_query ($sql);
 $row = mysql_fetch_object ($query);

 $id = $row->id;
 $msg = $row->message;
 $amount = $row->amount;
 $reciever = $row->reciever;

 $headers = 'From: noReply@anon.com';

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = '******************';
$token = '*************';

$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$client->account->messages->create( $reciever , 
        array(
                "From" => "**********",
                "Body" => "Test!"));

    //mail ($to, '', $msg, $headers);

 $amount--;

 if ($amount >= 1){
  $sql2 = "UPDATE smsque SET amount='$amount' WHERE id='$id'";
  $query2 = mysql_query ($sql2);
 }else {
    $sql2 = "DELETE from smsque WHERE id='$id'";
     $query2 = mysql_query ($sql2);
 }
?>
```

You can read more [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest) .